What are the consequences of rejecting a Marie curie doctoral position, after accepting it?
I have recently been selected for a Marie curie doctoral position and have to inform the selection committee about my decision within a week. I don’t want to let go of this opportunity, but I also have some really good applications going on. What happens if I reject the offer, after I have accepted it? Are there any personal/professionql/legal consequences?

It's ultimately your career.

Can you clarify what situation you are in? First you say you have only been selected (implying no action from your side), then you say you have already accepted (implying that you acknowledged and agreed to the offer).

@MisterMiyagi I understand that OP has not yet accepted, but is considering accepting the Marie Curie position and then rejecting it later if one of their other applications goes through. OP is asking what would be the consequences of this approach.

Have you considered telling the truth? If an offer has been made and you cannot honestly say yes or no to it, what about saying so - giving some idea of when you will be in a position to answer?
